Matrix Factorization/ Decomposition

Can every rectangular matrix be written as a product of two matrices?
What role does rank exactly play in the factorization of a matrix?
What is rank factorization?

PS: My goal is to understand the LoRA paper, where the essentially decompose a matrix $${\Delta W}_{m \times n} = A_{m \times k}B_{k \times n}$$ where k is a hyperparameter and the reason they do this is because they hypothesize the weight matrix to be of low rank.

Does this have anything to do with low-rank approximations of matrices. I believe not, I think the above is plain decomposition, yet I seek clarification.


You might read up on singular value decomposition.  It's a method of factoring a (rectangular) matrix into "relevant" (the rank-dimensional subspace) and "irrelevant" (the rest) parts.  It gives a factorization into three matrices, but $(AB)C$ and $A(BC)$ are factorizations into two matrices, so this isn't a real obstacle.

The answer to 1 is obviously yes, you can always write $M = MI$. Writing a matrix as a product with a small "middle" dimension, however, is only possible when the rank of $M$ is small. In particular, a matrix $M$ can be written in the form
$$
M_{m \times n} = A_{m \times k}B_{k \times n}
$$
is possible if and only if the rank of $M$ is less than or equal to $k$.

The product $M_{m \times n} = A_{m \times k}B_{k \times n}$ is sometimes called a rank factorization or a "rank-revealing" factorization because it gives evidence that the rank of $M$ is at most $k$.

In the context of the LoRA paper, $\Delta W = AB$ holds by definition within the framework of the model, and the entries of $A,B$ are parameters to be optimized. So, we force $\Delta W$ to have a low rank; $\Delta W$ having a low rank in this context is a constraint, not a hypothesis. By contrast, you can think of low-rank approximation as looking for matrices $A,B$ (with a given intermediate dimension $k$) that come as close as possible to a target matrix $M$. This typically arises when there is some degree of "error" in the entries of $M$ and we suspect the "true" version has low rank.

@BenGrossmann, The paper says - We hypothesize that the change in weights during model adaptation also has a low “intrinsic rank”, leading to our proposed Low-Rank Adaptation (LoRA) approach. Now the doubt I attempt to resolve in my head is, rank factorization is not a low rank approximation. Because when you simply multiply A,B to get M, you aren't losing any information while in an approximation you would. Hence, factorization is not low rank approximation and rather in the given usecase the factorization helps in reducing the number of parameters in calculations when k is small.

@xkcd101 Yes, the paper says that, but that supposes that there is some “true value” of $\Delta W$ being estimated here, which seems philosophically iffy. But this is a computer science paper, not a math or philosophy paper, so these hand-wavey justifications are just heuristics in the end of the day and the only extent of “correctness” that people care about is whether the resulting algorithm performs better.

@xkcd101 I agree with the latter part. The use of $A,B$ takes advantage of the (imposed) low-rank structure of $\Delta W$ to describe the same matrix with fewer parameters.
